# Create table with values from CTE based on rowid

Tags: sql, netezza

i am fasing a situation when i want select some data to created table. This data must be in joined between 2 tables based on a rowid. I know this can be done like i wrote, but it's not a correct way. Could you please suggest me a good way of my code.

```
CREATE TABLE new_bi_ccm_agg_mth  AS
WITH
RID_SEC AS
(
  SELECT rowid
  FROM bi_ccm_agg_mth t left join Base_ccm m on t.sub_id = m.sub_id and t.current_brand = 
  m.current_brand
 )
 select agg.* ,base.CURRENT_SEC FROM bi_ccm_agg_mth agg join base_ccm base
 where rid_sec.rowid = agg.r owid
```

Comment: I am trying, but I cannot make sense of your query... `rid_sec` does not appear in the `from` clause of the main `select`... And what is `agg join`?, I never heard of that type of join...

Comment: While I haven’t proofread the statement in detail, I think I can guess what you try to do, but I can’t say that I understand why you do it :) ... that being said: Im a little confused why you think this is the ‘not correct way’... does it give the wrong result? Does it perform poorly? Syntax error?